# How to obtain not-friend's public photos

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to get user public photos (friend's friend). When i just browse facebook I see them, but I can't access them via API. Neither

```
SELECT created, link, caption, images, like_info FROM photo WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid FROM user WHERE username = "...") OR object_id IN (SELECT uid FROM user WHERE username = "kaja.szuminska") OR object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject IN (SELECT uid FROM user WHERE username = "...")) ORDER BY like_info DESC LIMIT 0, 100
```

nor

```
.../albums
```

nor

```
.../photos
```

nor

```
.../photos/uploaded
```

works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you access friends pictures?  Are you getting an error message on the non-friend pictures?

Comment: Yes, I can access my friends picture. And i don't ger error message on friends' friend's picture. I just get one "cover photo" instead of all photos which I can access if I browse his/her profile in browser. Is it even possible?

Comment: Did you find an answer? Trying to do the same thing... One way is to scrape the page - but that's nasty

Comment: It seems that Facebook api doesn't allow to access friends' friend's photos. In my application I am going to write some photo caching code and spread app around my friends, so I will have cached version of my friends' friend's photos :P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access photos (public or not) you need permission. So it's only possible to access your photos (using `user_photos` permission) or friends' photos (using `friends_photos` permission).

If you want to scrape public photos, you can only do so by checking the user's public feed. I.e. making an API call to: `https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/feed` and then filter through the entries to see if any photos were posted.